# Java How can I recognize a photo color?

Tags: java, colors, awt

How can I recognise the color when i mouseover point to one postition of the photo?

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage("blueball.jpg");
Project() {
    jFrame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 320));
    jFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    colorLabelText.setBounds(new Rectangle(310, 210, 50, 30));
    colorLabelText.setText("Color :");
    colorLabel.setBounds(new Rectangle(370, 210, 100, 30));
    photoLabel.setBounds(new Rectangle(20, 20, 220, 250));
    photoLabel.addMouseListener(new RecognizeColorActionListener());
    jFrame.getContentPane().add(photoLabel);
    jFrame.getContentPane().add(colorLabelText);
    jFrame.getContentPane().add(colorLabel);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
}


     class RecognizeColorActionListener implements MouseListener {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX(); 
                       int y = e.getY(); 
                       int imgx = image.getMinX(); 
                       int imgy = image.getMinY(); 
                       int c = image.getRGB(x - imgx, y - imgy);
```

Error occurs  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!

Comment: How do you display your image?

Comment: I display it in a label the label location is photoLabel.setBounds(new Rectangle(20, 20, 220, 250));

Comment: Does it work ever, for example in the top-left corner?Do you draw the image from top-left corner of photoLabel?  What does image.getWidth(), image.getHeight() give you?

Comment: I can't find a constructor of java.awt.image.BufferedImage that takes a filename as a parameter, am I looking at the wrong class?

Comment: If using the getWidth and getHeight give the photo width and height 250 200, i move the label to top left corner got error as well. Coordinator out of bounds, btw thanks I solve it using robot.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is the the X and Y coordinates of the mouse do not correspond to the X and Y coordinates of the image. Change it to something like this:

```
int x = e.getX();
int y = e.getY();
int imgx = image.getX();
int imgy = image.getY();
int c = image.getRGB(x - imgx, y - imgy);
```

Don't quote me exactly on the syntax, but that is the basic idea.

Comment: Thanks, is it getMinX() , getMinY() ? I still getting this error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!

Comment: I am not sure, as I don't have a Java dev environment on the machine I am on now. What I described is the problem, but you need to play around with things to get it exactly right.

Comment: Maybe slightly different cause my image is bufferedImage